# Por que solo me imprime una palabra?

Tags: c#, string

Tengo un texto y quiero encontrar la palabra if y esta palabra esta varias veces repetida pero solo me la imprime una ves

```
  public void BuscarPalabras(string texto)
    {
        string mn = "if";

        int intIndex = texto.IndexOf(mn);
        bool resultado = texto.Contains(mn);
        if (resultado)
        {
            Palabras.Add(mn);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y el texto de ejemplo y el como lo lees ??

Comment: Lo mando como parámetro string texto

Comment: Pues agregalo al ejemplo...

Comment: Hola @Zeiker, puedes decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles y en caso de haber sido útiles darles un voto y marcar como aceptada la más te haya ayudado o gustado, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar **Linq** para ahorrar código:

```
public List<string> BuscarPalabras(string texto, string palabra)
{
   var listaPalabras = texto.Split(" ");
   var lista = (from p in listaPalabras
                where p == palabra
                select p).ToList();

   return lista;
}
```

Hacemos un método que va a devolver una **lista de string**, y va a recibir dos parámetros **string**, uno que será el texto, y el otro que será la palabra a buscar dentro de ese texto.

Dentro del método creado usamos la **función Split** que nos va a devolver un arreglo donde cada elemento de ese arreglo será un **string** que representa cada palabra del texto original. La **función Split** recibe como parámetro un caracter delimitador, que en este caso es el **espacio(" ")**, para poder separar el texto original atendiendo a este caracter delimitador.

Posteriormente usaríamos una consulta **Linq** para devolver una **lista de string** cuyo contenido serían las palabras que sean iguales a la palabra que se quiere buscar.

Para llamar a la **función BuscarPalabras** haríamos:

```
var palabrasIf = BuscarPalabras("Mi texto if hola if", "if");
```

Aquí en la **variable palabrasIf** devolveríamos todas las palabras **"if"** del texto **"Mi texto if hola if"**, es decir devolveríamos una lista con dos elementos cuyo valor seria **"if"**.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 3):

Dado el ejemplo que has proporcionado he hecho el siguiente ejemplo:

```
List<string> Palabras = new List<string>();
string texto = "if if texto if";
string mn = "if";

int i = 0;
while(i < texto.Length)
{
    int intIndex = texto.IndexOf(mn, i);
    if (intIndex != -1)
    {
        i = intIndex+mn.Length;
        Palabras.Add(mn);
    }
}
```

Algunas cosas a tener en cuenta:

- El "texto.Contains()" es innecesario ya que sino contiene directamente IndexOf te devuelve -1
- "IndexOf" te da solo un elemento (el primero que encuentra, por eso solo te da un único if en lugar de todos los que contenga, para ello debes usar la función sobrecargada "IndexOf(texto,posicion)" donde posición es la posición donde empieza a comprobar si existe el texto introducido en las posiciones siguientes.
- Siguiendo el punto anterior podrías simplemente hacer un bucle como el que hice de ejemplo de tal forma que si encuentras un "if" actualizas la nueva posición de inicio de búsqueda a la posición que se ha encontrado el if más el propio tamaño del if (sino le sumas el tamaño se quedará encontrando esa posición todo el rato ya que es justo donde empieza a buscar).

En el caso de tu nueva función simplemente deberías hacer esto:

```
public void BuscarPalabras(string texto)
{
    string mn = "if";

    int i = 0;
    while (i < texto.Length)
    {
        int intIndex = texto.IndexOf(mn, i);
        if (intIndex != -1)
        {
            i = intIndex + mn.Length;
            Palabras.Add(mn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por eso debes esperar a que explique el resto. Yo creo que el no esta recorriendo el texto... pero falta codigo a ver.

Comment: @Excorpion entiendo la intención pero creo que era lo que necesitaba por la forma de preguntar pero sí, está bien que ponga el código más completo